# Samsung TV unable to play .mkv files downloaded with Ubuntu

Tags: video, samsung, bittorrent, mkv

The weirdest thing is happening.

If I download .mkv files in Ubuntu, save them to my external drive and then try to play them on Samsung TV - the TV says that file format is unsupported.
But if I download the exact same file in Windows 10, then there are no issues and video plays just fine on my TV.

The external drive is formatted in NTFS format and i use qBitorrent for downlaoding mentioned .mkv files. Ubuntus version is 19.10

Why could this be happening?

I am attaching external drive to the TV directly.

Comment: The only thing I can suspect is encoding of file names. Are they in English?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, they are in english

Comment: That's a mystery. I suggest to find diff between files. First check if md5 match. If yes, it is a matter of file name encoding.

Comment: Remember years ago, I used to be asked by a program, if I wanted files to be renamed.  Don't remember if it was because of file name too long for windows or what.

Comment: Using qBittorrent https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent on both Ubuntu and Windows for your downloads? If so, suggest you rename them in Ubuntu to all uppercase including the .MKV extension before you detach the drive from the PC and attach it to the TV. If that does not resolve it, please download the same video with both Ubuntu and Windows, then compare the two as binaries. Maybe Ubuntu puts a different magic number in the .mkv when written?